# Compare Two Pandas Dataframes for any differences in python while ignoring few columns in comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using Python, I want to compare 2 pandas dataframes df1 and df2, the data in the df1 and df2 looks like below.

df1 dataframe:

| Database | Table | Column | Datatype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEV | Employee | EmpNo | Integer |
| DEV | Employee | EmpName | String |
| DEV | Manager | MngrNo | Integer |
| DEV | Manager | MngrName | String |

df2 dataframe:

| Database | Table | Column | Datatype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PROD | Employee | EmpNo | Double |
| PROD | Employee | EmpName | String |
| PROD | Manager | MngrNo | Integer |
| PROD | Manager | MngrName | String |
| PROD | Manager | MngrExp | Double |

I want to compare the df1 dataframe with df2, But while comparison I want to exclude the column "Database" and only compare the rest of the column values from both the dataframes. Hence My Final Result should look like below dataframe compared_df.

compared_df dataframe should have an additional column which indicates weather the given row has matching record in both dataframes or present only in one of them while ignoring the mentioned column values.

compared_df:

| Database | Table | Column | Datatype | CompareResult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEV | Employee | EmpNo | Integer | Only in df1 |
| DEV | Employee | EmpName | String | Both |
| DEV | Manager | MngrNo | Integer | Both |
| DEV | Manager | MngrName | String | Both |
| PROD | Employee | EmpNo | Double | Only in df2 |
| PROD | Employee | EmpName | String | Both |
| PROD | Manager | MngrNo | Integer | Both |
| PROD | Manager | MngrName | String | Both |
| PROD | Manager | MngrExp | Double | Only in df2 |

I tried to drop the "Database" column and later did the pandas merge, but in the final compared_df I could have the dropped columns info. Also tried the compare function but could not achieve this as sometime the number of columns in both dataframes might be different.

Answer (score 0):

Can you view this information a little differently?

Let's use [`pd.DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html#pandas-dataframe-compare),

```
df1.reindex_like(df2).compare(df2, keep_equal=False)\
   .rename(columns={'self':'Only in df1', 'other':'Only in df2'}).stack(1)
```

Output:

```
                Column Database Datatype    Table
0 Only in df1      NaN      DEV  Integer      NaN
  Only in df2      NaN     PROD   Double      NaN
1 Only in df1      NaN      DEV      NaN      NaN
  Only in df2      NaN     PROD      NaN      NaN
2 Only in df1      NaN      DEV      NaN      NaN
  Only in df2      NaN     PROD      NaN      NaN
3 Only in df1      NaN      DEV      NaN      NaN
  Only in df2      NaN     PROD      NaN      NaN
4 Only in df2  MngrExp     PROD   Double  Manager
```

Where all the NaN are values in both tables.

Comment: Actually I don't want to highlight the changes if its only different in the 
"Database" column values. And the output I am expected is something similar to what i mentioned in question because i Wanted to save that compared_df data frame to CSV file and display those changes in the application window table.
 
"CompareResult" column values can be different also, not exactly What I mentioned in question, But the format of the dataframe should be similar to what I mentioned please.